# Asynchronous service in java

Tags: java, hibernate, asynchronous, service

I have a problem with this async call:

```
public class myClass {
    protected final int idObj; 

    public void myMethod() {
        myService.getObj( new AsyncCallback<List<Object>>() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onSuccess(List<Object> listObject) {
                    idObj = listObject.get(0).getIdObj();
              }
    });


    if(idObj == 1) {
        //do something
    }
  }

}
```

The value `idObj` is equal zero at the first time and this if block isn't execute.
How to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an asynchronous call, that means that the code executed in your onSuccess method will be executed later. 
So the if statement is executed but at this time your value still 0.

You should put your if statement in the `onSuccess` method.